# Why does Visual Studio Code jupyter notebook outline (the table of content) show every single markdown block and how can I change it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Below is a screenshot of what I mean.  I'd like it to show only the headers of the notebook, not each and every single markdown block. Is there a similar way to changing this, like in JupyterLab, where you can toggle different outline options?

[image: a screenshot of my jupyter notebook outline (toc) in VS Code]

Comment: Sadly, this is still an unresolved [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147007).